The cardinality of regular Borel measures on an uncountable compact metrizable space.
Let us denote with $\mathfrak{c}$ the cardinality of the continuum, let $K$ be an uncountable compact metrizable space and let $M(K)$ be the set of all (complex valued) regular Borel measures on $K$. Consider the following statement:
Theorem. $|M(K)|=\mathfrak{c}$.
Now it is clear that, with $D(K)$ the set of discrete measures, then $|M(K)|\geq |D(K)|$ and as $|K|=\mathfrak{c}$, it must be that $|M(K)|\geq|D(K)|\geq|K|=\mathfrak{c}$, yet for the other direction, I have no idea how to proceed.

First, you can restrict yourself to uniformly bounded measures. Second, you can find a countable family of measurable sets such that the values on these sets determine a measure.

The space $K$ has a countable base and so we may assume that this base is closed under finite unions. As each open set in $K$ is a countable increasing union of elements of its base, and as each $\mu\in M(K)$ is determined by the values on the sets of its base, we have $|M(K)|\leq\mathfrak{c}$.
Hence, combined with your answer, we obtain $|M(K)|=\mathfrak{c}$.
